# Bash script iterate over files recusively and save output to file with identical name but different extension

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to recursively iterate over all my .html files in a directory and convert them to .jade using a bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in ./*.html ./**/*.html ; do
  cat $f | html2jade -d > $f + '.jade';
done;
```

Naturally the `$f + '.html'` bit isn't correct. How might I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s globstar

for f in **/*.html; do
    html2jade -d < "$f" > "${f%.html}.jade"
done
```

Comment: nice! Thanks, hey for bonus points -- do you know how to drop the .html from $ and append '.jade' ?

Comment: https://github.com/donpark/html2jade seems to indicate that `html2jade foo.html` automatically writes its output to `foo.jade`. No input or output redirection necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Concatenation is the default for most cases.

```
... > "$f.jade"
```

Also:

```
html2jade ... < "$f"
```

And:

```
... > "${f%.html}.jade"
```